# Google Sheets sum only filtered

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm starting just to get familiar with excel and google docs, i have some previous experience with it, but obviously not enough to understand why in the world this function wouldn't work

```
=(SUBTOTAL(9,Augusti!E:E))/(SUBTOTAL(2,Augusti!E:E))
```

All I get is Error, Augusti is a reference to another page inside the same doc,
the 9 stands for sum and the 2 stands for count correct me if I'm wrong, E:E contains a title row and the rest is just integers from 1 to 5.

All help is very much appreciated.

Regards

P.S.

while we're at it, is it possible to instead of typing Augusti and then september etc(A new page for each month) get the name from the column left of it to then use inside the above formula and get it evaluated correctly

**Solved - Answer:** 
Instead of comma `,` use semicolon `;`

Comment: Could you share an example of your spreadsheet so that we could access and understand better how it works?

Comment: Btw, are you trying to use the [AVERAGE](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240295) function? To make the month dynamic, you should use the [INDIRECT](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240292) function

Comment: yeah lol that would probably be alot better, but what i doubt it would work either since I cant get any of the 2 first once work

Comment: I've read on the link I gave you that text is ignored. So have a try with average and if still doesn't work, check your data formatting (note that it might fail because of a DIV by 0)

Comment: but if it counts all rows how can it divide by 0?

Comment: @JMax btw really appreciate you helping out :) really getting stuck here :P well im creating a demo to help you out some more down the road

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16279/discussion-between-breezer-and-jmax)

Comment: I solved this, instead of , comma your suppose to use semicolon ;

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved - Answer:** Instead of comma `,` use semicolon `;`

The End Result ended up like this

```
=SUBTOTAL(101;INDIRECT(A2&"!D:D"))
```

It works in regular excel gets a little bugged up still in google docs sheets